# Can we use upsert with update pipeline?

Tags: mongodb

Can we use {upsert: true} for mongoDB [update aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)? Any examples would be very appreciated.

Comment: yes it is possible, please provide more details what are you trying to do, any example would be appreciated. so we can help you through other possible options as well.

Comment: @turivishal please checkout this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68201328/push-with-positional-in-upsert-failes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, it will work.

```
db.getCollection('tmp5').update({
    "someKey":"nonExisting"
}, [
    {
        "$set": {
            "name": "ValToUpdate"
        }
    }
], {
    upsert: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground Sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_O3I7j2sWsv)

Comment: Please take a look to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68201328/push-with-positional-in-upsert-failes