# $push with positional ($) in upsert failes

Tags: mongodb

I want to `$push` a message document in a nested array with [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) in three case. The document is:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60db4301db16e85753c4eeef"),
        "to" : "111",
        "messages" : [
                {
                        "from" : "222",
                        "subMessages" : [
                                {
                                        "message" : "test",
                                        "date" : ISODate("2021-06-29T15:57:53.975Z")
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Case 1 (successfull): If specified `messages.from` field exists in `messages` array, the query succeeds like below:

```
db.pendingMessages.deleteMany({});
db.pendingMessages.insert([{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60db4301db16e85753c4eeef"),
        "to" : "111",
        "messages" : [
                {
                        "from" : "222",
                        "subMessages" : [
                                {
                                        "message" : "test",
                                        "date" : ISODate("2021-06-29T15:57:53.975Z")
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}]);

db.pendingMessages.updateOne(
{to: "111", "messages.from": "222"}, 
{$push: {"messages.$.subMessages": {message: "test2", date: ISODate("2021-06-29T15:57:53.975Z")}}},
{upsert: true}
);
```

case 2 (failed): If `messages.from` field doesn't exist in array, the [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) failes like below:

```
db.pendingMessages.deleteMany({});
db.pendingMessages.insert([{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60db4301db16e85753c4eeef"),
        "to" : "111",
        "messages" : [
                {
                        "from" : "222",
                        "subMessages" : [
                                {
                                        "message" : "test",
                                        "date" : ISODate("2021-06-29T15:57:53.975Z")
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}]);

db.pendingMessages.updateOne(
{to: "111", "messages.from": "333"}, 
{$push: {"messages.$.subMessages": {message: "test2", date: ISODate("2021-06-29T15:57:53.975Z")}}},
{upsert: true}
);
```

Error message:
"errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query."

Case 3 (failed): If document doesn't exist, the `{upsert: true}` must insert document with specified `to` field. The code is like below:

```
db.pendingMessages.deleteMany({});
db.pendingMessages.updateOne(
{to: "111", "messages.from": "333"}, 
{$push: {"messages.$.subMessages": {message: "test2", date: ISODate("2021-06-29T15:57:53.975Z")}}},
{upsert: true}
);
```

Error message:
"errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query."

How to overcome these two cases of error problems? Any codes and help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Case 2 and 3 are actually both upserts.  In case 2 the `messages.from` part of the filter doesn't match, so no matching documents are found.

Comment: @Joe you are perfect and you know what I want to do. So, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upsert will not work in nested documents in update query,

You can try a complex update with an aggregation query to handle your cases if you want to do it in a single query,

Let's take an example input and see example case wise,

**Case 1:** If specified `messages.from` field exists in `messages` array

```
var to = "111";
var from = "222";
var subMessage = {
  message: "test",
  date: ISODate("2021-06-29T15:57:53.975Z")
};
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qL7Adt_fYbn)

**Case 2:** If `messages.from` field doesn't exist in array

```
var to = "111";
var from = "333";
var subMessage = {
  message: "test2",
  date: ISODate("2021-06-29T15:57:53.975Z")
};
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BO-gJJ5qjis)

**Case 3:** If document doesn't exist

```
var to = "111";
var from = "333";
var subMessage = {
  message: "test2",
  date: ISODate("2021-06-29T15:57:53.975Z")
};
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yumpuPdgBn2)

---

Your final query would be,

- check only `to` condition in query
- update part, check the condition,

  - if `from` found in `messages` array then:

    - `$map` to iterate loop of `messages` array and check condition if `from` found then concat current `subMessages` array with new input `subMessage` using `$concatArrays`, `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with updated object
  - else from not found then concat new message object array in current `messages` array using `$cocnatArrays`
- `upsert: true`, to insert new document if to not found in the collection

```
db.pendingMessages.updateOne(
  { to: to },
  [{
    $set: {
      messages: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [from, { $ifNull: ["$messages.from", []] }] },
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$messages",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    subMessages: {
                      $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$$this.from", from] },
                        {
                          $concatArrays: ["$$this.subMessages", [subMessage]]
                        },
                        "$$this.subMessages"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              { $ifNull: ["$messages", []] },
              [
                {
                  from: from,
                  subMessages: [subMessage]
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }],
  { upsert: true }
)
```